Can a Program Certainly Distinguish Normal Distribution from a Discrete Finite One
Suppose we have two distributions $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. One of the distributions is normal $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and one is a discrete distribution with finite support, i.e. can be represented as a finite sum of weighted delta measures $\sum_{k = 1}^n c_k\cdot\delta_{b_k}$, but we don't know which one is which.
Now a natural question to ask if I can distinguish between these two situations. Quite trivially, no finite circuit with inputs being samples from the distributions can do this.
I am wondering if there exists a Turing machine with oracle access to the distributions which

terminates almost surely no matter what oracle is given
always correctly determines the class of the oracle: normal distribution or finitely supported one

My attempt: as we can fool any circuit, and any computation is a sequence of circuits $C_1(x_1), C_2(x_1, x_2), \dots$ with $x_i$ being different samples from the oracle, we may try to build a sequence of fooling distributions $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots$. Moreover we can build it in a way $\mu_k$ fools all circuits $C_1, \dots, C_k$, and try to take a limit $\lim \mu_i$ in a suitable topology, however it might happen that $\lim \mu_i \to \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ or the limit does not exist.
I have a feeling that it might have something to do with model theory, for example with notion of elementary equivalence.

What does it mean to have oracle access to a distribution? How is the distribution encoded on a tape?

@AlexKruckman, Thanks for your interest in the question! Yes, suppose there are two tapes: the first tape contains a sequence of i.i.d. samples from a normal distribution, and the second tape contains samples from an unknown distribution. I want to know which is the tape with normal samples.
Another problem is that Turing machines usually deal with finite alphabets, so a more suitable model would be the Real RAM model or a separate oracle that can evaluate arithmetic circuits

But no matter which formalism we chose, the idea behind it is simple: consider a programming language with basic operations {+, -, *, /}, variables, and control-flow statements (if, jump). Now suppose there is a rand() function which the next sample. The result must be yes/no which is yes for the normal case and no for not normal

Oh, okay. Suppose such a test exists. Then there exists a time $t$ that the test finishes in the first $t$ steps with positive probability. Construct an arithmetic circuit representing the computation for the first $t$ steps, and construct a discrete distribution which fools it.

I don't think this counterargument works. "The machine terminates almost surely no matter what oracle is given" does not imply "there exists a time $t$ that is independent of the oracle that the test finishes in the first $t$ steps with positive probability" -- at least, that implication is not obvious to me.

Thanks! Let's run the machine with the normal distribution input tape. Then must exists $t$ that the program terminates with positive probability

Ah, very nice! Thanks for clarifying.
